# Tail bounds of a mean of Laplace random variables

Tags: estimation, distribution-tails

Let's have three "true" values $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3 \in \mathbb{R}$. Their "true" mean is simply $y = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \mu_i$ where $N = 3$.

Now say I observe each "true" value with some error in measurement, and this error is distributed as a Laplace random variable, namely the observations are independent random variables $X_1 \sim \mathrm{Lap}(\mu_1; b)$, $X_2 \sim \mathrm{Lap}(\mu_2; b)$, and $X_3 \sim \mathrm{Lap}(\mu_3; b)$. Note that all three have the same scale $b$.

Now I simply say the "noisy" mean is $Y = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i$. How big is my error on this estimate? Namely,
$$
\Pr\left(\left|Y - y \right| > t\right) =
\Pr\left(\left|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \mu_i \right| > t\right) = ?
$$
It seems like a pretty standard thing to ask, but I've struggled to find a hint. These $X$ are not i.i.d. (because they have different means).

A tail bound for a single Laplace random variable is easy (beacuse we consider it zero-centered), but here it gets somehow more complicated.

I've considered some MGF approach and then Chernoff bounds, but it (1) doesn't look straightforward and (2) is only an approximation.

Am I missing something (so it's a known and solved problem) or is it really non-trivial?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent. All have the same scale but different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has $X_k = \mu_k + bW_k$, where the $W_k$ are i.i.d. with distribution Lap$(0,1)$. Hence
$$Y-y = \frac{b}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N W_k,$$
so for any $t \ge 0$,
$$P[|Y-y|>t] = P[|W_1+\cdots+W_N|>Nt/b].$$
So we are led to compute the distribution of $S_N := W_1+\cdots+W_N$.

The characteristic function is very simple: since the $W_k$ are i.i.d.,
$$\phi_{S_N}(\theta) = \phi_{W_1}(\theta)^N = \frac{1}{(1+\theta^2)^N}.$$
Using a Fourier (or Laplace) inversion, one can derive the
density function, which is a Sargan density. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4856056_Sargan_densities_which_one

Here is another method. A possible way to construct i.i.d. random variables with distribution Lap$(0,1)$ is to start from i.i.d. random variables $U_1,V_1,\ldots,U_N,V_N$ with distribution Exp$(1)$, and to set $W_k:=U_k-V_k$ for each $k$. Hence $S_N = (U_1+\cdots+U_N)-(V_1+\cdots+V_N)$ is the difference of two i.i.d. random variables with distribution Gamma$(N,1)$. We derive its a density as a convolution product. For every $s \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$f_{S_N}(s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{x>\max(0,-s)} \frac{(s+x)^{N-1}}{(N-1)!} e^{-(s+x)}\frac{x^{N-1}}{(N-1)!} e^{-x} \mathrm{d}s.$$
This density is an even function. Let us compute it for $s \ge 0$. $$f_{S_N}(s) = \frac{e^{-s}}{(N-1)!^2} \int_0^{+\infty} (s+x)^{N-1} x^{N-1} e^{-2x} \mathrm{d}s.$$
Using
$$(s+x)^{N-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1 \choose k} s^k x^{N-1-k},$$
one derives
$$f_{S_N}(s) = \frac{e^{-s}}{(N-1)!^2} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} s^k {N-1 \choose k} \frac{(2N-2-k)!}{2^{2N-1-k}} \text{ for } s \ge 0.$$
$$f_{S_N}(s) = \frac{e^{-s}}{(N-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{s^k}{k!} \frac{(2N-2-k)!}{2^{2N-1-k}(N-1-k)!} \text{ for } s \ge 0.$$
Set
$$P_k(s) = \sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{s^ \ell}{\ell!}.$$
Observe that
$$e^{-s}\frac{s^k}{k!} = e^{-s}\big(P_k(s)-P'_k(s)\big) = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \big(e^{-s}P_k(s)\big).$$
Hence, by integrating the density $f_{S_n}$ from $s$ to infinity, one derives
$$P[S_n>s] = \frac{e^{-s}}{(N-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} P_k(s) \frac{(2N-2-k)!}{2^{2N-1-k}(N-1-k)!} \text{ for } s \ge 0.$$
By symmetry, $P[|S_n|>s] = 2P[S_n>s]$ for $s \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Sargan density is new to me, so do you think a) deriving the density function is easy and b) given the Sargan density, how complicated is to derive the tail bounds (if even possible)?

Comment: @JohnDoe I found a way to continue the computations. I hope I did not make mistakes.

Comment: This looks great. Just to make sure, at the end, we would replace $s$ with $Nt/b$ to get the bound we begin with, right?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, indeed.